# Cancel and Re-create new PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am creating a notification in my Game. I want to show the notification if the player is not playing the game for sometime. I am using the below PendingIntent with alarm setup to create a notification. With this I am able to create notifications.

Question: If the player plays the game I need to cancel the existing pending Intent and create a new Pending Intent. I hope the Pending Intent flags will be used to achieve ? Please advice. Also it would be a great help if you could throw some light on the available Flags.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: Why do you need to cancel the `PendingIntent` and create a new one? Please provide more data so that I can answer your question properly.

Comment: Basically I will set the pending intent when the user leaves the game. this will trigger the notification after say 5 days. If the user played the game within 5 days, I should cancel the pendingIntent which is scheduled to tigger after  5 days. After this when the player quits the game I will setup the pending intent again which will be triggered after 5 days.

Comment: So you aren't using the `PendingIntent` to create a `Notification`. You are sending the `PendingIntent` to the `AlarmManager` to set an alarm. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to cancel a `PendingIntent` that has been created with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` is to hold on to a reference to that `PendingIntent` and then call `cancel()` on the reference.

If you no longer have a reference, you cannot cancel this `PendingIntent`.

You don't need to use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, so I wouldn't do that. It causes more problems than it solves.

Based on your answer to my question in the comments, what you want to do is to cancel the alarm. You don't need to cancel the `PendingIntent`. To cancel the alarm, just do this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

If you don't have any "extras" in the `PendingIntent`, then you can just create your `PendingIntent` like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

If you have "extras" in the `PendingIntent` that need to be replaced when you reset the alarm, you can create the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and your clear cut answer